# JNDI issue with weblogic + spring + eclipselink

Tags: spring, weblogic, eclipselink, jndi

I have an application in Spring 3.0 using eclipselink as persistence provider. The application is working fine in Jetty aplication server but gives an error when deployed in weblogic. Neccessary details are below

Spring xml file

```
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"
    ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiDataSource" jndi-name="${jndi.name}"
    resource-ref="true" />

<bean id="pum"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" />
</bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="my-persistence" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="pum" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver" ref="loadTimeWeaver" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:databasePlatform="${toplink.database.platform}" p:showSql="true" />

<bean id="jpaDialect"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
```

The properties file is as below

```
         jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
         jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB
         jdbc.username=***
         jdbc.password=***

         jndi.name=jndi/myDBjndi
         jndi.resourceRef=true
          jndi.enabled=true

        hibernate.database.platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    toplink.database.platform=org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.PostgreSQLPlatform
```

I have declared a  tag in web.xml

```
            <resource-ref>
    <descriptionMy DataSource Reference</description>
    <res-ref-name>jndi/myDBjndi</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The above works in Jetty but in Weblogic 10.3.4 I am getting the below exception

```
        ####<Aug 9, 2012 6:19:46 PM CST> <Info> <EclipseLink>  <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <f637fb3f44bc7f84:-2787ac98:1390ae3403e:-8000-000000000000001e> <1344507586988> <BEA-2005000> <2012-08-09 18:19:46.988--ServerSession(57821834)--Connection(55507026)--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
platform=>PostgreSQLPlatform
user name=> ""
datasource URL=> "null"))> 
        ####<Aug 9, 2012 6:19:47 PM CST> <Alert> <EclipseLink> <AdminServer> <  [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<anonymous>> <> <f637fb3f44bc7f84:-2787ac98:1390ae3403e:-8000-000000000000001e> <1344507587003> <BEA-2005000> <2012-08-09 18:19:47.003--ServerSession(57821834)--Local Exception Stack: 
               Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): 
            org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
            Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user  [null] and URL [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with your database platform
               at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.unableToAcquireConnectionFromDriverException(DatabaseException.java:376)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:91)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:330)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:293)
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the datasource defined and working well in the weblogic server?

Comment: Yes. I checked the JNDI in the weblogic server and it works correct.

Comment: Just to update. I changed the name of the persistence.xml to something else and this seems to have solved the problem. Dont know the exact reason though.

Answer (score 0):

It's because a Java EE container like `weblogic` autodetects `persistence.xml` files allocated in `/META-INF` folder and preloads the `Persistence Unit` (using the built-in implementation) but has no clue of the JPA properties set up at hibernate level. The persistence unit must only be boot strapped by `Spring`, so renaming the file to something else solved the problem.